# How do I "shoot and kill 5 rabbits" for the Sharpshooter challenge?

Tags: red-dead-redemption

I have been wandering around (which is extremely fun to do in Red Dead) for about 20 minutes now and I have yet to come across a single rabbit. Is there a specific region I need to be searching?

Comment: No special place.  Just be vewy vewy qwiet...

Comment: @Iszi I'll be sure to keep that in mind :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found 5 rabbits to shoot without too much trouble wandering around the [Warthington Ranch.](http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/Warthington_Ranch) There seems to be a fair amount of smaller animals running around here most of the time.

[Here is a link for wiki about the Rabbits.](http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/Rabbit)

Locations in accord with wiki:

- They can be found in the plains of Armadillo and other grassy, scrub-like areas.
- Rabbits are most common around The Hanging Rock just north of Armadillo, where they are most often seen at around 6 PM.
- Rabbits can also be found to the road that leads south of Warthington Ranch, along the river. They appear to be along the road in the morning. (8:30am onwards.)
- They can be found in certain rooms of the Tumbleweed mansion.